# Firefox loads with address bar highlighted instead of search engine?

Tags: firefox

For most years I can remember, a fresh Firefox page loaded a search engine page (yahoo, google, etc.) with my cursor blinking ready to search.

Now every window or tab I load begins with the address bar selected and blue, adding needless extra steps hundreds of times a day.

How can I fix this new cursor/address bar behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a search engine right from the address bar. If it's not working, then add a search engine in Settings -> Search. After that you'll be able to open a new tab and type your search query right away.

If you specifically need to open a new tab that would load some search enigine page then there're addons for that. For example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/new-tab-override (This one is verified and recommended by Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

This is an acknowledged bug and sources to a change made in Firefox release 105.  This change has been flagged for rollback to remediate this bug in the next possible Firefox release:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1784692

Comment: Firefox has just released version 105.0.1, which fixes this issue.